# How to launch shortcuts to a Virtual PC "XP Mode" application in a batch ... successively?

Tags: batch, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

First of all, I'm French, so forgive me my English (the dictionary is my friend) ...

*Here is my problem :* 
I have some trouble with a batch file to launch two virtual applications **successively** ...

*Presentation :* 
Windows 7 Pro (the host), Virtual PC with XP mode, two applications in the "virtual XP mode machine"

*Description :* 
The first application does several things ... 
The second one is a backup application to save data managed by the first one.
(The only way I found to save data is to install a backup software in the virtual machine, configure it to save in the host's disk and launch it as an "XP mode" application from the host.)

*Environment :* 
Needs to be managed by a "not smart" user, just in case (no, it isn't me ... though .. maybe :p)

*manual way :* 
Shortcuts to the applications in the XP mode machine have been created in the host menu (in W7, in the "virtual pc\xp mode applications" menu) and copied on the Windows 7 desktop.
The user should click on the first shortcut to launch the application, and after work, close his application and click on the second one to make the backup.
This works perfectly.

*Problem :* 
I know my users ... they will never click on the second one !!! :(((

*Sought goal :* 
Launch the second one (the backup) automatically after the end of the first application.
(The duration of using the first application is undefined, depending on the user's mood ...)

*Solution :* 
Create a batch command (for example) which will launch both applications (the first one and the backup) successively !!

*Problem met :* 
Impossible to make the batch wait for the end of the first one in order to launch the second one after it ! Both are launched simultaneously !

*What I've tried :* 
Content of the batch file :

```
start /B /WAIT "" "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Virtual PC\Windows XP Mode applications\myapplication (Windows XP  Mode)"  

start /B /WAIT "" "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Virtual PC\Windows XP Mode applications\myBackup (Windows XP Mode)"
```

==> despite the `/WAIT`, both virtual applications are launched simultaneously !!!

Can anyone help me ??

Thanks in advance.

Kawapoulpe

---

Maybe I'm stupid, but .... It doesn't work !

I've tried that :

Launch.bat :

```
call launch1.bat
start mybackup    (I don't put here all the line again)
```

launch1.bat :

```
start myapplication
```

Both are always starting simultaneously ...

Maybe because that's a link to a virtual application ... ?
It seems that the application is considered as finished, even if not ...

I looked for an another solution : making a loop to supervise the process of the virtual machine ... But it doesn't stop after the end of the application !!

Soo I don't know how to do it ...

KP

Comment: Your English is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use [`CALL`](http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icsw200.htm)

> `CALL` to call (=run) one batch script from another, and return to the original script after the called script has finishedscript has finished

START allows you to begin a second script without requiring the first script to wait for the second to finish.

In other words `START` allows you to do things in parallel, `CALL` allows you to do things in series.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

- As it has a problem to run the virtual application, I thought to create the batch IN the virtual machine and create a link to it in order to launch it from the host ...

==> And It works perfectly !!!

In order to have something better, I wouldn't see the Dos window ... 
The solution is with a vbs script which call the applications successively, but directly in the virtual machine. A link to the vbs script is made in the menu so the link appear in windows 7 and is able to launch the script which call both applications.

All is good !

If someone need the solution, just write me.

KP